# common == Not uncommon?

Tags: sentence-meaning, multiple-negation

I just read an article and found below sentence. I'm little bit confused about this sentence .

"It is `not uncommon` to have slides like that," she said.

Instead of using `not uncommon` author can use `common` ?

Comment: Which way are you trying to go? Your question title makes it look like you're trying to replace "common" with "not uncommon" but your sample sentence seems like you're doing the opposite.

Answer (score 5):

No, "not uncommon" cannot be used in place of "common".

"Common" and "uncommon" refer, in this context, to frequency of occurrence, and frequency is not a binary condition. Instead, frequency is measured along a scale, so there are frequencies between "uncommon" and "common." In particular, when it is "not uncommon" for an event to occur, the event happens at a greater frequency than it would if it were "uncommon", but that doesn't necessarily mean that event occurs so frequently that it is "common." For example, the frequency of the event could be such that it is classified "neither common nor uncommon."

In a similar way (though not exactly similar), the opposite of a negative number is a positive number, but when we say a number is "not negative," it is not necessarily "positive," as the number could be positive but it could also be zero.

Comment: +1 Welcome to ELL - Nice answer.  BTW - although it doesn't bother me at all, you will find that many people around here don't like the code tags - italics, bold and other notation are strongly preferred.

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided enough context provided to know whether *common* could be used in place of *not uncommon, but you have come across a not uncommon literary device known as ***litotes***, which the *Silva Rhetoricae* website at BYU [defines as](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/L/litotes.htm)

> Deliberate understatement, especially when expressing a thought by denying its opposite.
>   The *Ad Herennium* author suggests litotes as a means of expressing modesty (downplaying one's accomplishments) in order to gain the audience's favor (establishing ethos).

But without additional context, it is impossible to sayfor certain whether *not uncommon* in your example means the actual value is more or less or exactly equal to what you or the average person would consider to be *common*. Understatement can be used to soften a statement, but it can also be used to emphasize it through irony. You'll find litotes frequently [in speech](http://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2015/mar/26/litotes-the-most-common-rhetorical-device-youve-never-heard-of), where intonation and body language help communicate the real meaning, but in writing it can be much more vague.

> Parent: Is he a good student?
>   Teacher: Well, he's not a *bad* student.

(He is not a good student, but the teacher wants to euphemize the situation for the parent).

> Customer: My concern with the product is that they use the old API 
>   Salesman: I wouldn't call it a big problem.
>   Customer: I certainly wouldn't call it a *small* problem.

(The problem is, in fact, a significant one to the customer).

But

> Person 1: Did you all like the movie?
>   Person 2: We didn't hate it.

(Person 2 liked the movie just a little bit, just barely past the threshold of hating it. Or, Person 2 like the movie an average amount, and simply has no enthusiasm for it. Or Person 2 enjoyed the movie enormously, but does not want to be too outwardly enthusiastic. You simply can't tell without knowing about the delivery and about the people involved).

Answer (score 0):

To me, something that is *common* is more likely that something that is *not uncommon.*  People would vary on this, but I might say that something is *common* if it  has a >1/2 chance of occurring.  Something is *uncommon* if it has a <1/5 chance of occurring.

That means that a *not uncommon* thing has a greater than 1/5 chance.  So something that happens 30% of the time is not common, but neither is it uncommon.